# Unable to perform search based on numeric fields in Solr

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr and indexed an XML into Solr. My XML also includes some numeric fields. e.g.

```xml
<field name="weight" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

When I perform a Query on the Solr Admin Console, I am able to search based on "text" fields, but when I try to search based on numeric values, it shows nothing.

Comment: Can you share the query you are using? Also, are you sure the weight fields are populated?